# Should I use $<$ or $\leq$ when using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ language?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

In analysis, the difference between $<$ and $\leq$ can be sometimes very important. However, in many situations, it appears that they are interchangeable. For example, when defining the continuity of a function, we normally use $<$, but in fact, if we change all the $<$ to $\le$, the definition is equivalent:
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0\exists \delta> 0\forall x, |x-a|\leq \delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(a)|\leq \epsilon.
$$
Or when we are defining boundedness, we can use either $\exists M,|f(x)|<M$ or $|f(x)|\leq M$.

My question is: **Why sometimes we prefer strict inequality while other times we prefer non-strict inequality, even if they are equivalent?**

Comment: @EricWofsey Right. Just not careful

Answer (score 3):

It's just a matter of convenience.  Sometimes one way or the other is slightly easier to use in a particular argument, so you use the one that is more convenient.  For continuity, I would say the version with strict inequalities is the "right" definition because it is the one that generalizes more directly to continuity of maps between topological spaces.  But of course they are equivalent so that shouldn't stop you from using the nonstrict version when it is convenient to do so.